# can I change default style of validation error in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I want to change the red border color of validation error and backgroud color of tooltip message, how can I do it?

Comment: Do you use styles on your components?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own control template, that defines the style you want and then bind it to the control as below,

```
<TextBox Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource errorTemplateStyle}"
```

To know abt creating control templates to customize the control's visual structure, [check out this link](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/creating-ui/styles-and-templates/customizing-the-appearance-of-a-control-with-a-control-template)

Hope this helps..